# Como agrupar os dados na query e pegar o valor mais recorrente?

Tags: mysql

Tenho a seguinte tabela que salva minhas provas feitas:

```
id | materia | como_estudei | nota | valor | horas_estudadas
------------------------------------------------------------
1  | matemat | livro        |   4  |  10   | 10
2  | matemat | pdf          |   6  |  10   | 15
3  | portug  | video        |   5  |  10   | 23
4  | biolog  | pdf          |   6  |  10   | 45
5  | matemat | livro        |   7  |  10   | 20
```

Eu preciso agrupar por materias para saber o tanto de horas que eu estudei por materia,
o total de pontos e qual foi o metodo de estudo mais recorrente (que eu mais usei para fazer prova, nao contando horas ou pontos, mas apenas o numero de vezes que eu fiz prova)

Por exemplo:

Matematica ficaria:

```
materia - como_estudei  - total_pontos - total_horas
matemat - livro         - 17           - 45
```

Iria mostrar livro em vez de pdf, pois livro eu estudei 2 vezes e pdf apenas uma vez.

O Agrupamento eu já tenho a query:

`select materia, sum(nota) as total_pontos , sum(horas_estudadas) as total_horas from tabela group by materia;`

Pórem nao consigo ver como pego o metodo de estudo mais recorrente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para chegar neste resultado você poderia fazer um subselect. Neste subselect você agruparia o "como_estudei" por "materia" e "grupo", e retornaria o primeiro elemento de acordo com a contagem decrescente de ocorrências. Sua consulta ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
select T.materia, sum(T.nota) as total_pontos , sum(T.horas_estudadas) as total_horas,
(
SELECT como_estudei
FROM tabela 
WHERE materia = T.materia
GROUP BY materia, como_estudei
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1
) as como_estudei
from tabela as T
group by T.materia;
```